# Flutter firebase_messaging: ^6.0.13 failing with exception:

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I am trying to implement push notification with firebase_messaging: ^6.0.13,
Flutter: Build errors for firebase_messaging”

I have looked through all similar cases, Migrated my project to AndroidX but I still cannot resolve my Android build errors:

Followed procedures.

1. Flutter clean
2. flutter packages pub cache repair
3. Restart Android
4. Remake emulator nothing is working
5. Migrated project to AndroidX
6. Tried downgrading the plugin versions

**Exception:**

```
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              0.6s
Resolving dependencies...                                           2.5s
/home/rajeshpatil/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.13/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessaging/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
    onAttachedToEngine(binding.getApplicationContext(), binding.getBinaryMessenger());
                                                               ^        
  symbol:   method getBinaryMessenger()                                 
  location: variable binding of type FlutterPluginBinding               
1 error                                                                 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':firebase_messaging:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.        

* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              

BUILD FAILED in 2s                                                      
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         3.3s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**project-level/build.gradle:**

```
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app-level/build.gradle:**

```
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.helloworld"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**gradle.properties:**

```
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**Flutter Doctor:**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.10.7, on Linux, locale en_IN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.43.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: may be in inner file you also have to change target version according to this github isuue. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44760#issuecomment-573078891 check thisout

Comment: You have to upgrade flutter. Run ```flutter upgrade``` in terminal

Comment: @Viren i tried changing compileSdkVersion to 27 in app/build.gradle no luck..!!
or is there  anywhere else i have to make a change??

Comment: not only in app/build.gradle file but also in all other file. all suggested over their.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are working on an older flutter project, try a few things and see if these help.

1) Update your flutter SDK. You are currently using a pretty old version of flutter, and a beta build that was never a stable release. Even if this doesnt solve your problem it would be wise to upgrade. You can do so by running `flutter upgrade` in your terminal.

2) You may be trying to use an older version of certain firebase packages, including messaging. Try changing `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'`
in your project gradle.build to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'`. Do this only if updating your flutter SDK doesnt fix the issue, and if this doesnt help change it back.

3) Try increasing your minSDKVersion for the project in the app-level/build.gradle, in the past when I have had similar issues this fixed my problems around sdk version 21.

Comment: Okay @Jwildsmith ill try above all , very first ill try to do is flutter upgrade and will see if it resolves the issue

Comment: Hey @Jwildsmith...yes i did my flutter upgrade and switched to stable channel and it worked like a charm..!! Yes i'll mark this as an answer...it worked for me in my case. Sorry for late reply